# How to backup a table from local system and restore it to amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, amazon-rds, database-restore, mysql-backup

I have to create about 100,000 records in a table in a database on amazon R.D.S., buts its time consuming, to make the process quick i dropped the indexes of table and tried creating the records, but still its not enough, I am working on a R.O.R. project, and i thought it will be better to create these records locally and restore a particular table to live database on server, but not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend the route you're considering, especially if using Rails to create the records. I don't think you would save time in the end.

I recommend you use your local machine to test your import/creation script in small batches, say 1000-5000. Fine tune it by benchmarking, rinse and repeat. In fact, I would try design your script to handle the insert in independent batches, for example 10,000 if you're model has several relations.  If your script doesn't handle memory efficiently, your long running script could hog memory and eventually max out and result in the garbage collector running more and more frequently resulting in long pauses of the world.  This all depends on the complexity of your models but in my experience, small batches are best.

When you think your script is ready, run in on production.